# Open link in Tablepress table in New tab

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using Tablepress one on of my Wordpress sites and I am using Jquery to open links when people click in the table using the following code:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.tablepress-id-15').on( 'click', 'tr', function( event ) {
    var $a;
    if ( $( event.target ).is( "img" ) ) {
      return;
  }
   $a = $(this).find('a').last();
   if ( $a.length ) {
      window.location = $a.attr('href');
   }
 } );
});
   // ]]></script>
```

This bit of code checks if there is an image in the last row with a link and then opens that link when a user clicks.

Now I want to open the link in a new tab but after trying different option nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
window.location = $a.attr('href');
```

To:

```
 window.open($a.attr('href'), "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.open` instead:

```
window.open(
  $a.attr('href'),
  '_blank'
);
```